# float right alignment issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/H2CPq/). Notice the arrow icon, it's in first row (in Chrome and IE). When I open the same in Firefox its alignment gets changed. Why does it happen? What's the solution?

```
.arrow{
   float:right;
}
```

PS: The solution which `Imran` and `Kheema` are suggesting is not what I want. I don't want to change the HTML structure, in that case I'll have to make changes in a lot of places.

Comment: what is the position you want to add that arrow ?

Comment: I want the same behavior as Chrome, arrow in first row. `<a href="doc4.html" name="doc4" target="_blank">doc4</a><span class="arrow arrow_up"></span><div style="" class="toggle"><div>`

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I've updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this Demo. the arrow have same position in Firefox as appears in Google.

so what i do here. I switch the line i.e. put the `span`tag before the `a` tag.

```
<span class="arrow arrow_up"></span>
<a href="doc4.html" name="doc4" target="_blank">doc4</a>
<div style="" class="toggle"><div>
```

Another Solution is remove the `white-space: nowrap;` from `th` and `td`

```
th, td {
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

Check the updated **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/dihugale/1/edit)**.

Comment: Thanks, the next solution is what I wanted.

Comment: Nice, but in-case you want to keep your no-wrap add this css: `th > *, td > *{ white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Can you explain what does the above mean? Never seen something like that.